# How to copy and paste a range of data to multiple worksheets and without header

Tags: vba, excel

I am totally new to VBA and trying to setup some macros to copy a range of data from one worksheet to another 2 worksheets within the same workbook.

I have found some code that enables me to copy the whole range and paste it at the next empty row in the worksheet2 (Column A to Q). However, I am unable to figure out how to copy it without the header (1st row in worksheet 1) and also how to loop it to paste to worksheet3 (Column E to U).

***The Marco I would like to setup is to allow me to copy the table from row A2:Q2 down to the last row in column A on sheet1 (each time the last row is different), then paste (as values) to the next empty row in column A on sheet 2. It then paste the same table to the next empty row in column E on sheet 3. 
Once information is copied over it would remove the information from A2:D2 and also all information from the 3rd row down to the last row on sheet1.***

Please help as I am confused by the information I have found on the forum and internet.
Any assistance would be much appreciated.
Thanks

```
Sub ArchiveReminder()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim Lastrow2 As Long
Sheets("MailMerge-Reminder").Activate
    For i = 1 To 17
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Lastrow2 = Sheets("Archive-Reminder").Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For b = 2 To lastRow
        Sheets("Archive-Reminder").Cells(Lastrow2, i).Value = Cells(b, i).Value
        Lastrow2 = Lastrow2 + 1
    Next
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Update - Just discovered there is a problem with the code I used (i.e. if the last record in column B on sheet 2 is cell "B10" and column A is cell "A11", then the information in column B will be pasted from cell "B11" and not "B12".

Comment: If you don't want to start on the first row (including header) but on the second row (without the header) then you should use `For b = 2 To Lastrow` instead of `For b = 1 To Lastrow`. If you want to do the same again then just copy your sub and change the name to the other sheet name. Of course, the latter of the two will bulk up your code significantly. Yet, there are so many things you could improve and shorten that this wouldn't matter too much anymore.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I have changed the code as per above and it was able to copy without the header. Unfortunately I have just discovered the code I had would not work the way I wanted. To make things easier, I have added a description in my original question. Hope this make sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should have included the code you are using. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub ArchiveReminder()

    Dim rngToCopyFrom As Range

    With Worksheets("MailMerge-Reminder").Columns("A:Q")
        Set rngToCopyFrom = .Resize(LastColumnsRow(.Cells) - 1).Offset(1)
    End With

    PasteRangeValuesToWorksheet rngToCopyFrom, Worksheets("Archive-Reminder").Columns("A:Q") '<~~ paste values to 1st worksheet
    PasteRangeValuesToWorksheet rngToCopyFrom, Worksheets("Archive-Reminder2").Columns("E:U") '<~~ paste values to 2nd worksheet

End Sub


Sub PasteRangeValuesToWorksheet(rngToCopyValuesFrom As Range, rngToPasteTo As Range)
    'pastes values from the range passed as the first parameter to the range passed as the second parameter
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With rngToPasteTo
        lastRow = LastColumnsRow(.Cells) '<~~ get last non empty row between all columns of the range to paste to
        .Resize(rngToCopyValuesFrom.Rows.Count, rngToCopyValuesFrom.Columns.Count).Offset(IIf(lastRow = 1, 0, lastRow)).Value = rngToCopyValuesFrom.Value '<~~ paste values
    End With
End Sub


Function LastColumnsRow(rng As Range) As Long
    'gets last non empty row between all columns of the passed range
    Dim maxRow As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    With rng
        For Each cell In .Resize(1)
            lastRow = .Parent.Cells(.Parent.Rows.Count, cell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            If lastRow > maxRow Then maxRow = lastRow
        Next cell
    End With
    LastColumnsRow = maxRow
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, unfortunately an error message appears when I tried to execute your code - Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. Also I have just discovered the code I had would not work the way I wanted. To make things easier, I have added a description in my original question. Hope this make sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: PasteRangeValuesToWorksheet rngToCopyFrom, Worksheets("Archive-Reminder2").Columns("E:U") '<~~ paste values to 2nd worksheet

Comment: That's because "Archive-Reminder2" is a "dummy" name I put there just for a test. You have to use sheet names actually in your workbook

Comment: Hi, thank you for getting back to me so quickly, it works perfectly, there is just one last task I would like to add to the code which is to clear the information on sheet 1 after copied over to sheet 2 and 3, would it be possible to advise how I can combine the following code to the one above?    Range("A2:D2").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Rows("3:500").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("A2").Select